# define different instantiation of a templated static class member

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to wrap some stuff in a simple templated class:

```cpp
template <int dim>
class internal {
    static unsigned int table[dim][dim];
};
```

And fill the table for different templated parameters:

```cpp
template <>
unsigned int
internal<1>::table[1][1]  = {{0}};

template<>
unsigned int
internal<2>::table[2][2] =
                {{0, 1},
                 {2, 3}
                };
```

But I run into a duplicate symbols problem:

```cpp
12 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

Something is wrong, but what?
p/s/ a quick search over topic does not relieve similar questions.

Comment: Nameclash with a keyword `internal`?

Comment: Where are your definitions? They should be in your .cpp file, not in your .hpp file.

Comment: @bash.d `internal` is not a keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions need to be in a .cpp file. Since you surely won't give those definitions for tons of dimensions, you'll want to get compiler errors if a wrong dimension is picked. Your implementation could look like this then:

**Header:**

```
template <int dim>
class internal {
    static unsigned int table[dim][dim];
    static_assert(dim <= 3, "Dimension too big!");
};
```

**Source:**

```
template <>
unsigned int
internal<1>::table[1][1]  = {{0}};

template<>
unsigned int
internal<2>::table[2][2] =
                {{0, 1},
                 {2, 3}
                };

template<>
unsigned int
internal<3>::table[3][3] =
                {{0, 1, 2},
                 {3, 4, 5},
                 {6, 7, 8}
                };
```

**Note:** Unlike normals static template member variables, you need not and must not define the table in the header, because you have no templated versions of it but all full specializations.

Comment: @ArneMrtzt btw, is there a way to define those static variable in kind of a for loop?

Comment: @Denis depends. There are template metaprogramming tricks to fake loop constructs. If you update your question with the for loop you have in mind and give me a comment here, I can try to show you how it could be done.

Comment: i see. i created another question. Meanwhile try to do it myself, but not yet there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168688/fill-static-templated-array-with-metaprogramming