# fill static templated arrays with metaprogramming and variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I know that there are easier ways to do it, but 
I would like to initialize at compilation time 
the map from unrolled index of 2d array to its general format.

I would like to do this without needing to instansiate the array object.

Below I define the map from `array[][]->array[]`.
Now I wonder how to do the opposite:  `[] -> [][]`
without hardcoding the chosen mapping scheme.

I guess that should be possible using metaprogramming and variadic templates.
But I tried using it for the first time just a couple of days ago, 
so it takes a while to get used to ;)

header:

```
template <int dim>
class internal {
    static unsigned int table[dim][dim];
    static unsigned int x_comp[dim*dim];
    static unsigned int y_comp[dim*dim];
};
```

source:

```
//1d case:

template <>
unsigned int
internal<1>::table[1][1]  = {{0}};

template <>
unsigned int
internal<1>::x_component[1] = {0};

template <>
unsigned int
internal<1>::y_component[1] = {0};

//2d case:

template<>
unsigned int
internal<2>::table[2][2] =
            {{0, 1},
             {2, 3}
            };

// here goes some metaprogramming tricks to initialize
// internal<2>::y_component[2*2] = ...
// internal<2>::x_component[2*2] = ... 
// based on mapping above, i.e. table[2][2];
// that is:
// x_table = { 0, 0, 1, 1 }
// y_table = { 0, 1, 0, 1 }
// 
// so that :
//
//  index == table[i][j]
//  i     == x_comp[index]
//  j     == y_comp[index]
```

**EDIT1:**

or just tell me that it's not possible and I hard-code everything or use 
integer division to relate the two index representations.

**EDIT2**:
i would prefer to stick with definition of arbitrary arrays. 
Of course one can do without, as in answer below using integer division.

Those arrays can be really arbitrary, for example:

```
template<>
unsigned int
internal<2>::table[2][2] =
            {{3, 0},
             {2, 1}
            };
```

Comment: Wich values would you like to be in `internal<2>::x_component` etc?

Comment: @ArneMertz i modified question at the end to make it clear

Comment: can you use C++11 features as `std::array` and `constexpr`? If you only want to have those indices, you won't need that whole array stuff.

Comment: @ArneMertz std::array and constexpr are fine. I do use constexpr in other places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using arrays:

Given a table with unique entries from 0 to dim^2-1, you can write `constexpr` lookup functions for the i and j of a given table entry:

```
constexpr unsigned get_x_comp(unsigned index, unsigned i=0, unsigned j=0) 
{ return table[i][j] == index ? i : get_x_comp(index, ((j+1)%dim ? i : i+1), (j+1)%dim); }

constexpr unsigned get_y_comp(unsigned index, unsigned i=0, unsigned j=0) 
{ return table[i][j] == index ? j : get_y_comp(index, ((j+1)%dim ? i : i+1), (j+1)%dim); }
```

These will recursively call themselves, iterating through the table and looking for `index`. Recursion will eventually end when the given index is found and `i`/`j` of that index is returned.

Combine that with the C++14 `std::integer_sequence` mentioned by Jonathan to initialize the arrays:

```
template<unsigned... I>
constexpr auto make_x_comp(std::integer_sequence<unsigned, I...>) -> std::array<unsigned, sizeof...(I)> { return {get_x_comp(I)...}; }
```

## Using metafunctions instead of arrays:

In some cicumstances, one might not even need arrays. I assume you want to the `table` to contain consecutive indices from 0 to dim^2-1. If that's the case, `table`, `x_comp` and `y_comp` are only simple compiletime functions with the following attributes:

- `table(i,j) := i*dim + j`
- `x_comp(index) := index / dim` (integer division)
- `y_comp(index) := index % dim`

Depending on if you have C++11 features available, the implementation will be different, but both times without arrays.

**Note:** the following implementations will assume that the numbers stored in `table` are consecutive from 0 to dim^2-1. If that is *not* the case, you'll have to roll your own appropiate function for `table` and use the above `get_x_comp` and `get_y_comp` implementatio

## C++11:

```
template <unsigned dim> //use unsigned to avoid negative numbers!
struct internal {
  static constexpr unsigned table(unsigned i, unsigned j) { return i*dim+j; }
  static constexpr unsigned x_comp(unsigned index) { return index/dim; }
  static constexpr unsigned y_comp(unsigned index) { return index%dim; }
};
```

You can call these functions like normal functions anywhere, especially anywhere you need compiletime constants. Example: `int a[internal<5>::table(2,4)];`

## C++03:

```
template <unsigned dim> //use unsigned to avoid negative numbers!
struct internal {
  template<unsigned i, unsigned j>
  struct table{ static const unsigned value = i*dim+j; };
  template<unsigned index>
  struct x_comp{ static const unsigned value = index/dim; };
  template<unsigned index>
  struct y_comp{ static const unsigned value = index%dim; };
};
```

Using these metafunctions is a bit more clumsy than in C++11, but works as usual with template metafunctions. Same example as above: `int a[internal<5>::table<2,4>::value];`

**Note:** This time you can put the (meta-)functions in the header, since they are not non-integral static member variables any more. Also you do not need to restrict the template to small dimensions, since everything will be calculated well for dimensions less than `sqrt(numeric_limits<unsigned>::max())`.

Comment: Thanks Arne for answer. Sorry for not saying it straight away that i need those arrays. Otherwise it's true, one can do without arrays easily by integer division.

Comment: @Denis you can use Jonathan's approach for populationg `table`, I added a meas to populate `x_comp` with constexpr functions. See my edits.

Comment: Nice. The first part of this answer is great, but the rest assumes consecutive numbers in `table` and the edit to the answer makes it clear that may not be the case (which makes my answer wrong.) To handle the general case the solution must use the `get_x_comp` and `get_y_comp` functions to search for values in `table`, which I failed to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: I didn't understand the rule for populating `x_comp` and `y_comp` when I wrote this, now that I see that part of the question this answer is not really relevant, because I was incorrectly assuming `table` only contained consecutive integers.  The answer is left here anyway because Arne's (much better) answer refers to it.

---

I would replace the arrays with `std::array` and use the C++14 `integer_sequence` utility:

```
template <int dim>
struct internal {
    static std::array<std::array<unsigned, dim>, dim> table;
    static std::array<unsigned, dim*dim> x_comp;
    static std::array<unsigned, dim*dim> y_comp;
};

template<unsigned Origin, unsigned... I>
constexpr std::array<unsigned, sizeof...(I)>
make_1d_array_impl(std::integer_sequence<unsigned, I...>)
{
    return { { I + Origin ... } };
}

template<int N>
constexpr std::array<unsigned, N*N>
make_1d_array()
{
    return make_1d_array_impl<0>(std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned, N*N>{});
}


template<unsigned... I>
constexpr std::array<std::array<unsigned, sizeof...(I)>, sizeof...(I)>
make_2d_array_impl(std::integer_sequence<unsigned, I...> seq)
{
    return { { make_1d_array_impl<I*sizeof...(I)>(seq)  ... } };
}

template<int N>
constexpr std::array<std::array<unsigned, N>, N>
make_2d_array()
{
    return make_2d_array_impl(std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned, N>{});
}

template<int dim>
std::array<std::array<unsigned, dim>, dim> internal<dim>::table = make_2d_array<dim>();
```

That fills the `table` array correctly. I'll have to think about it a bit more to populate `x_comp` and `y_comp` as you want, but it's doable.

You can find an C++11 implementation of `integer_sequence` at https://gitlab.com/redistd/integer_seq/blob/master/integer_seq.h

Comment: I don't quite see how did you use the definition of `internal<2>::table[2][2]`?

Comment: I didn't use `internal<2>`, I showed how to define and populate `internal<N>::table` _for any N_. I don't understand what values you want in the x and y arrays though

Comment: values are in comment section. It is effectively the map between two representations of 2d array - pair of indexes (x,y) and a single (unrolled) index. This `internal<2>::table[2][2]` defines pair->index; The question is how to populate index->pair;

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry if I'm not answering the question directly (or at all), but I don't really understand what you're asking. I think what you're saying is that you want to initialize at compilation time a way to have an array of size *N* x *M* represented as a 1D array?

I've included code that allows you to allocate non-square dimensions. I've built this in "easy" C++ so if you're just getting into templates it's not so difficult to follow.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
template <typename T, typename std::size_t N, typename std::size_t M = 1>
class Array {
    T* data;
public:
    Array<T, N, M>() : data(new T[N * M]) {
        T temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                data[i * M + j] = temp++;
            }
        }
    }
    /* methods and stuff
}
```

Where M is the column number, so you'd use this like:

```
int main(void) {

    Array<float, 10, 10> myArray;

    return 0;
}
```

Remember to call `delete` in the destructor.

Comment: that requires an instantiation of an object of this class. Which is exactly what i don't want to do. Thanks for the answer, anyway